# jQuery change event not firing in IE8 on multiple <select> when more options are selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a multi-select list and do some stuff when the selection changes.  I have the following code in an ASP.NET MVC view (Model.AvailableChoices is an IEnumerable):

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(
m => m.Value,
Model.AvailableChoices.Select(s => new SelectListItem() {Text = s, Value = s,})
, new {@class = "StringChoiceMetadataFieldViewModel"}
)
```

It generates the following html:

```
<SELECT id="MetadataFields_10__Value" name="MetadataFields[10].Value" multiple="multiple" >
  <OPTION value="Wakka">Wakka</OPTION>
  <OPTION value="Splat">Splat</OPTION>
  <OPTION value="Bang">Bang</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

And I'm binding to the change event via jQuery (v1.6.4):

```
$('#someDivAboveTheSelect select').change(function () {
alert('change event');
});
```

---

The change event handler is not getting hit when I ctrl+click to change the selection, unless I do 
something that causes the *first* selection in the list to change.  So if I select Wakka then ctrl+click Splat I don't get the event.  However if I select Splat then ctrl+click Wakka I do.

Normal click changes work just fine.  And everything works just fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Does anybody know what's going on here?  I suspect it might be something about needing IDs on the select options...if that's the case, how do I make that happen with MVC?

Thanks

Comment: As a starting point, try using valid HTML, quote the option values, i.e. `<OPTION value="Wakka">Wakka</OPTION>`. Not sure if that fixes it though.

Comment: Oops - I got that output using the "Copy Outer HTML" in the IE dev tools which leaves off the quotes.  I'll fix it in the post...

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if this will help:

```
$('#someDivAboveTheSelect select').change(function () {
    alert('change event');
});

// blah blah use feature detection instead
// in reality, sometimes browser hacks are needed
// not quite sure about this case, though
if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 8) {
    $('#someDivAboveTheSelect select').click(function () {
        $(this).trigger("change");
    });
}
```

Comment: I know. I would love to know the "real" answer myself, and hope it's not a case of "because IE is just broken".

Answer (score 0):

Wow this is really an issue...

If you don't figure out a cleaner solution to this here's what you do:

1. Use the .click event instead of .change and compare the last selection with the current one to simulate "change" functionality
2. Submit a bug report to Microsoft & demand they fix IE

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Append~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

After thinking about why this problem is the way it is, the only reason of why IE behaves the way it does, is that there is a coder somewhere out there in a big building in a cubicle that, while writing the event handler code in IE, wrote some code similar to this:

```
Selection = HookedSelect.FirstSelectedElement;
If (Selection != LastSelection)
{
    LastSelection = Selection;
    Raise Event Change(Selection);
}
```